# Apply CSS3 Filter Property to specific part of an Image

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-filters

I'm working on a project to display different pictures on a wall Like

[image]

I want to apply css3 filter property "grayscale" on only picture frame area, not on the whole image
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Any idea how to do that, maybe by applying some x,y coords to filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use an SVG filter referenced via CSS to filter a sub-section of your content. The filter window is defined by the dimensions specified in the feFlood.

```css
img {
 filter: url(#partgrey);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/90/Jos%C3%A9_Villegas_Cordero_-_The_Slipper_Merchant_-_Walters_37105.jpg">


<svg>
  <defs>
  <filter id="partgrey" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <feFlood x="0.1" y="0.1" width="0.2" height="0.35"/>
    <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
    <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Take a div, give it that image as background.
- Now place a div over the painting in the image
- Give that inner div the save background as the image, but offset the background

---

**Crude example as demo (might not be 100% exact overlay):**

```css
#Outer, #Inner{
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kczi.jpg');
}
#Outer{
    position: relative;
    width: 687px;
    height: 687px;
}
#Inner{
    position: absolute;
    left: 19%;
    top: 5%;
    width: 420px;
    height: 320px;
    background-position: 49% 10%;
     filter: grayscale(100%);
 }
```

```html
<div id="Outer">
    <div id="Inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. Actually I can't use image twice. Here is an example I think it might help
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

Comment: @RameezIqbal This is the best solution there is. Could you provide your code so we can see what you are working with? The w3school link you provided isn't relevent to your question. That is just an image map that links to a different page.